# Creating an 'or' statement in a list Python

Tags: python, arcgis

So I've tried a few ways to search for my problem but nothing seems to give me the exact answer I am looking for. Here is my code for context:

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = "F:\\dir"

# Check out any necessary licenses
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

# Local variable:
Inpoints = "F:\\dir\\x.shp"

fdata = "_01,_02,_03,_04,_05,_06,_07,_08,_09,_10,_11,_12"
fdata = fdata.split(",")

#initalizing the list
Inraster = []

#build list of inputs
   for year in range (1983, 2014):
     for line in fdata:
      date = str(year)+line
      Inraster1 = ["rfe"+date+".tif", date]

    Inraster.append(Inraster1)

# Process: Extract Multi Values to Points

arcpy.gp.ExtractMultiValuesToPoints_sa(Inpoints, Inraster, "NONE")
```

For the fdata line, I'd like it to read as or, so it doesn't search for every raster as some of the rasters in the ranges for various years don't exists (eg - month 1 1985 may exist but month 1 in 2003 does not).

Not sure if that makes sense?

(Notes: Using python 2.7)

Comment: How would you know if `rfe1983_01.tif` exists but `rfe2003_01.tif` doesn't?

Comment: I have a large dataset of 1500 tif files starting in 1979 to present I need to read through and extract data from. I've gone through the list to see what's all missing, so instead of writing separate codes, I was hoping to combine it into one.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're creating that dataset (is it files on your desktop? Is it an excel file? A word document? A JSON? A pickled list? Is it stored in memory? Did you etch it on stone tablets?) but it seems trivial to simply refer to that list rather than building a brand new one....

Comment: I'm exporting values from those listed rasters to a shapefile; I want to get the code to read the raster values. But my code is too simple as it expects each one of those files to be there but they aren't. I was just wondering if there is a way to run the code without that issue. I'm not creating anything new with this code, just appending data in a .shp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import os

BASEDIR = "f:\\dir"

#build list of inputs
Inraster = []
for year in range (1983, 2014):
    for month in range(1, 13):
        fname = "ref{:04d}_{:02d}.tif".format(year, month)
        # is there actually a file by this name?
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(BASEDIR, fname)):
            Inraster.append(fname)
```

Comment: I feel like this is taking an extra unnecessary step. Can't we just use a regex on `os.listdir(BASEDIR)` to check for `r"ref(?:19|20)\d\d_\d\d\.tif"` and operate on each file rather than building a list of possible files then checking to see if it exists? (+1 anyway)